# FastAPI-mysql docker. mysql return (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1')

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

this is my docker-compose-yml file. first i tried to run the db service it work fined and docker running successfully. but when I run the app service, in the terminal it says connected to database but I get an error as (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1')

```
 version: '4'
    
    services:
      app:
        build: .
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        env_file:
          - .env
        depends_on:
          - db
        links:
          - db  
      db:
        environment:
              - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
              -
        image: mysql
        ports:
          - "3307:3307"
        env_file:
          - .env
```

enter image description here

Comment: The default port of MySQL is `3306`. Probably, you might need to map the ports like this - ***`"3307:3306"`***

Comment: I tried, same error

Answer (score 0):

What environment variable is the FastAPI app using to connect to the MySQL host?

If you're using docker-compose networking, services need to use the container name in order to reach each other (i.e. `mysql://db:3307/db_name_here`) not `localhost`.

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

More information on networking can be found in their docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Also worth noting, since you're using `links` you can set aliases as well like so:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  web:
    build: .
    links:
      - "db:database"
  db:
    image: postgres
```

[Links Docs Source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links)

Comment: mysql://db:3307/db_name_here
what do you mean db in here? i have mentioned the same string. i got an different error

Comment: How are you trying to connect to MySQL inside your FastAPI app? Can you show the env vars and/or config being used? It's hard to tell what's going wrong without that. What I meant was when connecting to MySQL inside a docker-compose you need to use the container name as the hostname for internal DNS

Comment: fastapi database connection->

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL=mysql+pymysql://'+USER_NAME+':'+PASSWORD+'@'+HOST+'/'+DB

env vars
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=3307
USER_NAME=root
PASSWORD=root
DB=eventDb

this is how it has been connected inside fastapi. I understand docker not working because I'm using localhost. how to overcome this. highly appreciatable for your valuable time

Comment: try changing `HOST` to `db` which is the container name for your MySQL DB based on your `docker-compose.yaml`

Comment: it saying as unknown database

Comment: @Raxz can you please show logs and/or the exact issue you're getting in the question. Kinda hard to help without it. I assume changing the HOST to `db` got rid of the initial error `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1`?

Comment: `links:` is obsolete, and you should just delete it.  When you're making connections between containers you always need to use the "normal" port number, for MySQL 3306; `ports:` aren't used or required here.