# Problem in Connecting FastAPI Server and MySQL databse using Docker-Compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

I have been trying to connect my FastAPI server and MySQL Database using Docker-compose. However, it keeps showing the following error when I run `docker-compose up  --build`.

Some of the posts (e.g., [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68874683/fastapi-mysql-docker-mysql-return-2003-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127)) on the Internet and StackOverflow suggest changing the value of `DB_HOST` similar to the MySQL service name, specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I tried that option as well, but I am still getting the same error.

Could you please help me, with what changes I need to make in order to run MySQL and FastAPI server using docker-compose?

The following is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql-db:
    container_name: mysql-db
    image: mysql:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE='admin'
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='admin'
    expose:
      - "3306"
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  backend-server:
    container_name: "backend-server"
    build: .    
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
```

My database configuration file is the following

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData

DB_USER = "root"
DB_PASSWORD = "admin"
DB_HOST = "mysql-db"
DB_PORT = "3306"
DATABASE = "admin"


connect_string = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?charset=utf8'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DATABASE)


engine = create_engine(connect_string)
meta = MetaData()
conn = engine.connect()
```

My Dockerfile for FastAPI Server

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR '/backend' 
COPY ./requirements.txt  ./
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
COPY .  .   
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app"]
```

My error log is as follows:

```
Starting mysql-db ... done
Recreating backend-server ... done
Attaching to mysql-db, backend-server
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20 20:57:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
backend-server    | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 613, in connect
backend-server    |     sock = socket.create_connection(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
backend-server    |     raise err
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
backend-server    |     sock.connect(sa)
backend-server    | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
backend-server    | 
backend-server    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
backend-server    | 
backend-server    | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3256, in _wrap_pool_connect
backend-server    |     return fn()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
backend-server    |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
backend-server    |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
backend-server    |     rec = pool._do_get()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
backend-server    |     self._dec_overflow()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
backend-server    |     compat.raise_(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
backend-server    |     raise exception
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
backend-server    |     return self._create_connection()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
backend-server    |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
backend-server    |     self.__connect()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
backend-server    |     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
backend-server    |     compat.raise_(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
backend-server    |     raise exception
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
backend-server    |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
backend-server    |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
backend-server    |     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
backend-server    |     self.connect()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
backend-server    |     raise exc
backend-server    | pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql-db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
backend-server    | 
backend-server    | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
backend-server    | 
backend-server    | Traceback (most recent call last):
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
backend-server    |     sys.exit(main())
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
backend-server    |     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
backend-server    |     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
backend-server    |     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
backend-server    |     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 437, in main
backend-server    |     run(app, **kwargs)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 463, in run
backend-server    |     server.run()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
backend-server    |     return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
backend-server    |     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
backend-server    |     return future.result()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 67, in serve
backend-server    |     config.load()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 458, in load
backend-server    |     self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
backend-server    |     module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
backend-server    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
backend-server    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
backend-server    |   File "/backend/./main.py", line 2, in <module>
backend-server    |     from models.dbschema import  dbExceptionMessage, dbMaterialMaster
backend-server    |   File "/backend/./models/dbschema.py", line 3, in <module>
backend-server    |     from config.db import meta, engine
backend-server    |   File "/backend/./config/db.py", line 15, in <module>
backend-server    |     conn = engine.connect()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3210, in connect
backend-server    |     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
backend-server    |     else engine.raw_connection()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3289, in raw_connection
backend-server    |     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3259, in _wrap_pool_connect
backend-server    |     Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2106, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
backend-server    |     util.raise_(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
backend-server    |     raise exception
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3256, in _wrap_pool_connect
backend-server    |     return fn()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 310, in connect
backend-server    |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 868, in _checkout
backend-server    |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 476, in checkout
backend-server    |     rec = pool._do_get()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
backend-server    |     self._dec_overflow()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
backend-server    |     compat.raise_(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
backend-server    |     raise exception
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
backend-server    |     return self._create_connection()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
backend-server    |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
backend-server    |     self.__connect()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 666, in __connect
backend-server    |     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
backend-server    |     compat.raise_(
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
backend-server    |     raise exception
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
backend-server    |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
backend-server    |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
backend-server    |     return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
backend-server    |     self.connect()
backend-server    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 664, in connect
backend-server    |     raise exc
backend-server    | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql-db' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
backend-server    | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
backend-server exited with code 1
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20 20:57:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20 20:57:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.28-1debian10 started.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:57:59.047590Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.28) starting as process 1
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:57:59.145611Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:57:59.171249Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012585] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:57:59.171538Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012654] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO disabled.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:57:59.678151Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:58:00.317516Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:58:00.330970Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:58:00.475268Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:58:00.476155Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:58:00.481201Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:58:00.599555Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql-db          | 2022-03-20T20:58:00.601446Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.28'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Comment: The "connection refused" error, followed by the database startup messages, indicates your application is starting up before the database is ready to accept connections.  Docker/Compose/`depends_on:` on its own isn't quite able to ensure the database is fully functional before the application starts up, but see [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) for some alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the log, the database server refuse to connect, so it seems like the problem is with neither `FastAPI` nor `docker-compose`; because your configurations are correct.
*(Assuming that you tried to connect MySQL database from some other code or server. In other words, you are sure you can connect to database from a client.)*

You are using `PyMySQL` connection for `SQLAlchemy`. So, as stated in [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql), your database connection string should be like:

```
mysql+pymysql://<username>:<password>@<host>/<dbname>[?<options>]
```

The difference is the **port** attribute.

So, if you try a connection string like following, you should be able to connect to the database:

```
connect_string = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}?port={}?charset=utf8'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_HOST, DATABASE, DB_PORT)
```

*NOTE:* *Also, in some examples, I saw adding `?host=` option in addition to `port`; so you may try to use that too if it doesn't work.*